# WebAuthn: using algorithm -47 (ES256K) for PublicKey fails

Tags: fingerprint, ecdsa, webauthenticator

I'm trying the basic user registration with WebAuthn following https://webauthn.guide/#registration . If `pubKeyCredParams: [{alg: -7, type: "public-key"}]` is changed to `pubKeyCredParams: [{alg: -47, type: "public-key"}]` *i.e.* from `ES256` to `ES256K` (equivalently: `secp256r1` to `secp256k1`) the registration fails with

[image: Error message when using ESP256K]

**The question**: What can be the cause?

I use emulated authentificator from Chrome DevTools with protocol `ctap2`, transport `internal`, support for resident keys, user verification and large blobs.

Comment: Ran into the same issue, would be really helpful if anyone knows the why the this problem happens. My current thinking is the device doesn't support secp256k1 on the hardware level, e.g. Apple only supports the secp256r1 curve for EC keys.

Comment: I have the same problem - seems like an Apple issue (or maybe a feature!?)